# Quadrado e o cubo de uma mesma variável em C

Tags: c

Boa galera, eu estou com uma dúvida. Meu professor estava ensinando funções em C e pediu para nós fazermos uma função com uma variável que calcule o quadrado e o cubo e imprima os dois.

O meu código até então ficou assim, mas ele só consegue retornar uma só, ou quadrado ou cubo.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Assinatura da função (DECLARAÇÃO)
int fSoma(int *valor1);

int main(void) {
    int numero[1], numero2, resultado[1], valor1, x;

    printf("Digite um numero aleatorio"); 
    scanf("%d", &numero[1]);

    for (x=0; x<2; x++){

    resultado[x] = fSoma ( &numero[1] );

    printf("%d \n", resultado[x]);

}
}

    int fSoma(int *valor1){
    int mult[1], x;
    for (x=0; x<2; x++){

    mult[0] = pow(*valor1, 2);
    mult[1] = pow(*valor1, 3);


    return mult[x];

}


}
```

Comment: O teu professor te pediu uma mesma função que calcule o quadrado e o cubo ou pediu uma função que calcule o quadrado e uma outra que calcule o cubo? Além disso, você já pode usar `struct`?

Comment: Uma função só, eu posso usar qualquer coisa, portanto que eu consiga ler em um unica função, o cubo e o quadrado

Comment: Repense sua lógica de acordo com a semântica dos comandos. Quando você faz `return[x]` ele sai da função e retorna ao chamador. Não adianta colocar o `return`dentro de um loop, na primeira chamada ele encerrará a função. Note também que quando você declara `mult[1]`está reservando memória para **1** int, como, me parece, você quer memória para **2** ints precisaria declarar: `int mult[2]` e os índices possíveis seria `0` e `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vejo que está usando ponteiros, mas da forma errada. Uma possibilidade seria usar uma função assim:

```c
void quadrado_cubo(int valor, int *quadrado, int *cubo) {
    *quadrado = valor * valor;
    *cubo = valor * valor * valor;
}
```

E então você chama com isso:

```c
int numero, quadrado, cubo;
scanf("%d", &numero);
quadrado_cubo(numero, &quadrado, &cubo);
```

Comment: Tentei usando o seu, também não consegui

Comment: E tipo, ali no void quadrado_cubo(int valor, int *quadrado, int *cubo) ele quer um valor só, por exemplo void quadrado_cubo(int valor)

Comment: @JoãoMarceloTavares A função tem que devolver os valores ou ela tem apenas que mostrá-los com `printf`?